# VBA: is it possible to declare function return type?

Tags: vba

Is it possible to declare type of the value returned by the function in VBA (visual basic for applications, MS)?

As far as I understand, VBA is statically typed (excluding situations with late binding and Variants). And it is possible, for example, to declare type of the input parameters. But I don't see the way to declare type of the return value. Is it possible?

Comment: `function a(x as integer) as string`  for example.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement

Comment: Right. Somehow I confused Sub and Function while reading docs. Rookie mistake.